# ¿Se puede utilizar un z-index en un div transparente?

Tags: html, css

Tengo un `<div>` que quiero que pase sobre los elementos de la página, sin que tenga color de fondo, es decir, transparente.

El problema es que al no tener color, es como si no estuviese, fíjense en la foto (el div rojo) pasa sobre los elementos de la página:

http://prntscr.com/va2bwf

Pero al sacarle el color, esto no pasa.

http://prntscr.com/va2cpz

¿Cómo hacer que esté ahí, pero no tenga color, y a su vez pase por encima de los elementos?

```css
#topbardiv{
        z-index: 1000;
        width:100%;
        top:0;
        position:fixed;
        background-color:whitesmoke;
        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    }
    
    #menu{
        padding-inline-start: 0;
        text-align: center;
        list-style: none;
        border:30px;
        margin:0;    
        align-items:flex-end;
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
        border-bottom:rgb(214, 190, 173);
        border-bottom-width:4px;
        border-bottom-style:solid;
        box-shadow: 0 0 90px rgba(34,25,25,0.3);
        
    }
    #baraux{
        position:fixed;
        
        z-index:2000;
        padding-bottom:265px;
        margin-top:-300;
        padding-right:3000;
    }
```

```html
<div id="baraux">
        <div id="topbardiv">
            <img id="howlies" src="logo.png" alt="logo">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a id="inicio" href="#top">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a id="accesorios" href="accesorios.html">Accesorios</a></li>
                <li><a id="comida" href="comida.html">Comida</a></li>
                <li><a id="ofertas" href="ofertas.html">Ofertas</a></li>
                <li><a id="informacion" href="#divotros">Informacion</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Por favor, pulsa en [edit] y añade el código aquí para que podamos ver el problema. Lo ideal es dar un [mcve].

Comment: No debería haber problema para utilizar `z-index` con un div transparente, es una técnica bastante común. ¿Cómo falla cuando lo implementas? ¿Cómo pones los estilos del transparente?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Falla en el momento que los elementos no desaparecen desde la punta del triangulo, y pasan por debajo de este, el estilo le pongo background-color:transparent;

Comment: Ya has mirado en el inspector del navegador? Desde allí puedes ver los elementos que hay en tu página web, y ver donde está tu `div`